# How do I extend the expiration of Dart's Dartium webbrowser?

Tags: dart

I need to avoid upgrading to Dartium 35 or higher because I have an AngularDart application that requires applyAuthorStyles and Chromium 35 has removed that feature. I need to defer the upgrade until I can successfully migrate my application away from its NgComponent-derived classes.

How do I get around Dartium's built-in expiration without altering my system clock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](http://blog.abelsky.com/2014/01/22/how-to-disable-dartium-expiration/) you can set an environment variable:

```
# Set to Jan 2020
export DARTIUM_EXPIRATION_TIME=1577836800
```

However, [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=13312) says that the change to support the environment variable was reverted.

So, this env variable may work; but if it doesn't, you're probably out luck, since the code looks pretty hard-wired.

Comment: I don't need it anymore (coincidentally the exact problem I had that necessitated a migration was solved about a week later), but thanks anyway. :)